# iPhone 4 not accepting jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, animation

Simple question: I found the answer about implementing "touch" functions instead of "click" and the decent chunk of code, however i'm stuck.

```
$('#info-button').bind("click", function() {
    $('#slidecaption').toggle('slow', function() {

    });
});
```

That's the code I have(*used to be plain ol' click then a mate said change to bind*).

How do I write it to include a touch function? My knowledge isn't good enough to fathom the answers going on here. Internet beers for the most helpful answer.

Comment: `touch or touch_start` have you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some library in your case. My experiences are that http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/ has worked well in my projects.

Example:

```
$('#info-button').hammer().on("tap", function() {
    $('#slidecaption').toggle('slow', function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: i still cant get this to work on iPhone 5.... any thoughts? Wordpress wont let me include the hammer library due to a plugin conflict.

I have read the bind "click" works on iPhone5, yet it wont let me toggle under bind. What to do?

Comment: [link]http://www.jquery4u.com/events/jquery-toggle-live-bind/
This seems to imply a way around it using a live bind.

Can someone help me out by showing me how it fits into my code using my class names? Just a little confused by it.

peACE